Non-empty chambers for Hassett spaces
Fix some $n\geq 4$. Hassett constructed different compactifications of $M_{0,n}$ that depend on the input data of what he calls collections of weight data, which are elements of the set of admissible weights, which is defined as:
$$
\mathcal{D}_{0,n} = \{A=(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in\mathbb{Q}^n\,\vert\, 0<a_i\leq 1, \sum a_i>2\}.
$$
Then, he proceeds to describe a wall and chamber decomposition for this set as follows. Given any subset $I\subseteq [n]$ such that $|I|\geq 2$, we define the wall $W_I$ as the hyperplane $\sum_{i\in I}a_i = 1$. The chambers are the connected components of $\mathcal{D}_{0,n}\setminus \cup W_I$ as $I$ ranges along all possible such subsets.
Given an element $A$ in a non-empty chamber $C_A$, I am interested in determining all chambers that are adjacent to $C_A$. Here we say that to two chambers $C$ and $C'$ are adjacent if there is a wall $W$ such that $\overline{C}\cap\overline{C'}\subseteq W$ is a facet for the polytopes $\overline{C}$ and $\overline{C'}$.
Clearly a necessary condition is that the inequality that changes along the wall is independent of all the other inequalities defining the chamber. For example, if $a_1+a_2>1$ and $a_1+a_2+a_3>1$ in one of the chambers, it is impossible to flip the second inequality while leaving the first one unchanged. I conjecture that this is the only obstruction to having a well-defined simple wall crossing. In other words, adjacent chambers correspond precisely to wall crossings along "minimal" inequalities. However, I am having a hard time proving this.
As far as I can see the whole argument boils down to showing that flipping a minimal inequality results in a non-empty chamber, because once we know this the wall that is being crossed will be a facet for both of them by definition. Any help if greatly appreciated.
